# how calculate top property for fixed element

Tags: css, html

:)
when i dont set top/left properties for an element fixed what acccured??
please see this sample code:

```css
#fixed-menu{
    background-color:#ba4444;
    border-top: 5px solid #0892cd;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:9999;
    box-shadow:rgb(128, 128, 128) 0px 5px 15px 0px;
}
#wrapper{
    height:900px;
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-top:100px;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="fixed-menu"></div>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
<body>
```

with above code,fixed-menu also have 100px margin-top!!!!why?????
...................
how calculated top property???

Comment: just use `position:relative` to `fixed-menu` div and it'll work as expected

Comment: Iif i give top:0px that work...
but i want understand why when i dont set top:0px, fixed-menu will have margin-top:100px as wrapper have margin-top 100px.....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once an element has been fixed with `position: fixed`, the three properties `left`, `width` and `right` together determine the horizontal position and size, relative to the window. (CSS uses the more general word viewport; a window is an example of a viewport.)

You need at most two of the three properties, i.e., `left & width`, `right & width`, or `left & right`. Setting just one of the three, or none at all is also possible. In that case, CSS will use the element's natural (“intrinsic”) size and/or position, as needed, for any properties that are left at their default value ('auto').

The same holds for the trio `top`, `height` and `bottom`. You need to set at most two of them: `top` if you want to control the distance from the top of the window, `bottom` to control the distance from the bottom, and `height` if you want to specify a fixed height.

I hope that answers your question. For further reading you can refer to this **[link](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/menus.en.html)**

Answer (score 0):

> **Tip :** Fixed position is free flow guy in the document window. Based on the element present before the fixed element aligns itself next to it.

In your example there's no elem before fixed div but the following wrapper div you are setting the margin top to 100px. which affects the viewport. So you can imagine the viewport for fixed element starts below the 100px mark set by the wrapper div.

you can see removing the margin in wrapper div or set the wrapper position to fixed with margin top 100px. you will get the idea.